# How to plot multiple rows of a matrix along third dimension in a plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, keras

I have a matrix of dimension (3,25000), where each row is a speech signal of dimension (1,25000). I want to plot the rows of thee matrix along the third dimension in a 3D plot , something similar to this -

![1]https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/mediastore_new/IEEE/content/media/6221036/8642545/8249740/deb3-2787717-large.gif

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mplot3d.

Think of the first row as a categorical axis denoting the "moods" (as in your link), the second row as the y-axis and the third row as the z-axis.

Note: It isn't clear from your question how the category is associated with your numpy array. However, you can't use a character array of the first row of moods in matplotlib to plot data so you have to retrieve the indices at those categories.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x,_=pd.factorize(<list of categories aligned with numpy array>[0]) #retrieving indices at categories
y=<your_array>[1]
z=<your_array>[2]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z)
.
.
.
```

Lastly, you can set your x-axis labels as:

```
ax.axes.set_xticks(x)
ax.axes.set_xticklabels(<insert list of your labels>)
```

Comment: The rows of the numpy array are speech waveforms belonging to different emotion categories which i want to plot along the third axix as in the figure. The x axis represent the time and y axis represent the amplitude and the z axis different emotions stored as row of the matrix.

Comment: to plot this in Python in 3D as show in your link, switch: x axis to be emotion, y axis to be time and z-axis to be amplitude.